# Disconnecting rear lock assembly

Tags: honda, locks

Still working on the 2000 Honda CRV. Trying to get the lock assembly out of the door so I can work on it, but I'm having trouble disconnecting it from the outside door handle.

part #8 plugs into the handle assembly, but I can't see how to disconnect it.  Is there a special trick to getting this disconnected, or should I just yank and not be afraid to break it?

Both part #8 and the handle are plastic, so I'm a bit hesitant because I don't want to have to order a bunch of extra parts because I broke them.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out part 8 is not designed to be easily removed from the handle assembly.  I ended up removing the exterior handle assembly from the door, and unscrewing part 8 from the lift arm of the lock assembly.

Answer (score 2):

Pry it with a small screwdriver, it's just a snug fit. This first picture is what that rod is held in with

[image]

Some latches like the one below have a retaining clip that hooks onto the rod, but your's isn't one of them.

[image]

Comment: Had to take the entire assembly out and unscrew the handle from it, turns out this piece is not easily removed.